# Delete a feed item from a facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

Is it possible for a facebook app to delete a particular item from the user's feed? These items could be generated from friends or other apps installed by the user or friends' apps posting on the user's wall.

If this is possible, what kind of permissions are required to do so?

Answer (score 0):

see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

> You can delete a post as long **as your application created the post**. You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID object with publish_stream permission.

so answer to your question is: no, you cannot delete a random post.

Answer (score 0):

Application only allowed to remove posts created by that application. You will not be able to remove content posted by other users/applications.

Removal (as well as publishing) of posts require `publish_stream` permission.

If you know the `id` of feed story just issue `DELETE` request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?method=delete
```